# How to change the frame index for rendered animation frame names?

Tags: rendering, animation

I need to render the same animation multiple times, changing a couple of things in the scene (like camera placement). So while the animation is 24 frames (1-24), I need the second round of rendering animation to create frames called "anim0025.png", "anim0026.png", ... "anim0048.png" instead of "anim0001.png", "anim0002.png", etc.

How can I automatically boost the index for the filenames by 24, so this happens?
I tried setting the prefix to "anim0025" but Blender didn't interpret anything from that, it outputted "anim00250001.png".

Using 2.83

Comment: That's a pretty specific feature. Can't you just render them as anim_a, anim_b and combine them in editing? All the workarounds I can think of are fairly tedious.

Comment: Yes, but I just batch-renamed using Adobe Bridge, which is free. I had to run the same animation 12 times so I had to change the name/path settings 12 times, or move the files that got generated to a new location each time

Comment: what is your end-goal

Comment: I just wanted the freedom to transform frame indices for the file names. Blender can already let you enter mathematical expressions (SO USEFUL!!!), and it would have saved me time to not have to batch-rename anything or shuffle files around between renders. "Transform frame indices for the file name" means that I can bump or deduct every frame number by a specified amount. This is done in most programs by telling it what number to begin with for the first file. If I had been able to do this, I would not have needed to leave Blender between rounds of rendering.

Comment: you can import the animation n times in the VSE and press render again, that way you get a continous frame number. Ofc. you can do that in any software, that"s why I asked about the end goal. Why do you need continous frame numbers?